# Count down timer speeds up

Tags: javascript

I have a timer that counts down every second. The timer is used for a game: the user has up to 15 seconds
to answer to a question. Let's say the game has 10 questions. The timer works great for the first question
, but then, speeds up more and more with every question. Any suggestion is more then welcome. Thank you!

Code is here:

```
var timeInSecs;
var ticker;
function startTimer(secs) {
    timeInSecs = secs;
    ticker = setInterval("tick()", 1000); // every second
}
function tick() {
    var seconds = timeInSecs;
    if (seconds > 0) {
        timeInSecs--;
    }
    else if (seconds == 0) {
        document.getElementById("timeExpired").innerHTML = "Time expired!";
    }
    document.getElementById("countDown").innerHTML = seconds;
}
function myStopFunction() {
    clearInterval(ticker);
}​
```

Comment: When you say, "speeds up more and more," do you mean that is less than 15 seconds or do you mean that somehow a single tick is less than a second?

Comment: How are `myStopFunction` and `startTimer` being called? Is there a chance that you are running two timers at the same time by calling `startTimer` again before the previous `startTimer` interval is cleared?

Comment: put complete code otherwise its getting hard to find out where r u wrong

Comment: Sample - http://jsfiddle.net/H9ZE7/

Comment: @mawcsco a single tick is less than a second

Comment: hard to say without the call to StartTimer, but my best guess is that its being called more than once. try puting a breakpoint on the function. EDIT: check Trasvesty3 fiddler link and press the button twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
else if(seconds==0)
        {
            // you should stop the timer here, and clear the interval
            myStopFunction();
            document.getElementById("timeExpired").innerHTML = "Time expired!";
        }
```

Edit: A side note

It is better to pass the function `tick` to the interval, rather than a string to evaluate. Using eval is generally a dangerous thing to do, and less efficient.

```
setInterval(tick, 1000)
```

Edit: Another side note

You can write the tick function a lot less verbosely (and without the extra variable `seconds`)

```
    function tick(){
        document.getElementById("countDown").innerHTML = timeInSecs;
        if(! timeInSecs--){
            myStopFunction()                
            document.getElementById("timeExpired").innerHTML = "Time expired!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Billy Moon Thank you! I made the changes and now it is working great for all questions. Thanks gain!

Comment: nothing says thank you like a nice fat green tick, and an upvote!

Comment: Ok, I will accept your thanks then, but I think you should still be able to accept answers (as nobody else possibly could).

Comment: I am sorry being in a hurry to say thank you. I am new on stackoverflow(it was my second question). I do not know exactly how everything is working here. I do apologize.

Comment: @Barmar Can I accept more than one answer?(I know, it is a stupid question, but sometimes, one person gives me a suggestion for a part of the problem and somebody else for another part of the problem).

Comment: No, you have to pick the one that was the most helpful. When you get enough reputation you can upvote the others.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use variable `second` instead of `timeInSeconds`--, in the `tick()` function.

Because you have given the value of `timeInSeconds` to `seconds`. Maybe this will help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're clearing the interval when you reach 0.

You defined `myStopFUnction()` but probably never call it when seconds == 0.

Try:

```
else if (seconds == 0) {
    document.getElementById("timeExpired").innerHTML = "Time expired!";
    myStopFunction();
}
```

Also, you should use `===`

Comment: Thank you! I cleared the interval now when it is reaches 0. It is working now correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
var timeInSecs;
var ticker;
function startTimer(secs) 
{
    timeInSecs = secs;
}

function tick() {
    var seconds = timeInSecs;
    if (seconds > 0) 
      timeInSecs--;
    else if (seconds == 0) 
    {
        document.getElementById("timeExpired").innerHTML = "Time expired!";
    }
    document.getElementById("countDown").innerHTML = seconds;
    ticker = setInterval("tick()", 1000); // every second
}

function myStopFunction() 
{
    clearInterval(ticker);
} ​
```