# timer speeds up on second round onwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I have borrowed some JS code to help me create a timer for 65 seconds. My JS knowledge is basic but I managed to modify the script to work the way I want it to. However when I click on the `play` button the timer speeds up from the second round onwards.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="rightCol">
        <span id="countdown" class="timer">Timer About to Start! </span>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Play" id="play">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS:**

```
var seconds = 65;

function secondPassed() {
    var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
    }
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Time's Up!";
            document.getElementById("passage_text").disabled = true;

    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
}
 
var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);

$("#play").click(function(){

    seconds = 65;
    var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);

    $('#passage_text').attr('disabled', false).focus();
    $("#passage_text").val('');



});
```

I read some of the other answers similar to mine [Count down timer speeds up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646298/count-down-timer-speeds-up) but I don't fully understand how the `secondPassed()` function works to fix it.

Comment: The code is setting two timers, not one. Get rid of one. Also, it will take longer than 65 seconds to run since *setInterval* doesn't run at exactly the specified time and doesn't self–correct if it drifts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear interval on `play` functionality too and make `countdownTimer` global. Also it's better to pass function handler to `setInterval` instead of string as this will work as `eval` function and not recommended

```
var seconds = 65;
var countdownTimer = null; // make it global

function secondPassed() {
    var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
    }
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Time's Up!";
            document.getElementById("passage_text").disabled = true;

    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
}

countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000); // removed var and passing handler instead of string.

$("#play").click(function(){

    seconds = 65;
    clearInterval(countdownTimer); // clear interval
    countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000); // removed var to use global countdownTimer variable

    $('#passage_text').attr('disabled', false).focus();
    $("#passage_text").val('');
});
```

See my JS comments above

Comment: Consider `seconds < 1` rather than `== 0` otherwise if the global *seconds* goes negative for some reason the timer will run forever.